# Identify arrays with same first element and sum other elements based on index

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge, duplicates

Hi Javascript Experts,

I have an array as below

```html
[["Database_Config",   19, 0,  0, 0, 0,  0]
["Database_Config",   0,  26, 0, 0, 0,  0]
["apiDomainListener", 0,  0,  1, 0, 0,  0]
["apiDomainListener", 0,  0,  0, 1, 0,  0]
["Database_Config",   0,  0,  0, 0, 27, 0]
["Some_other_Config", 0,  4,  0, 0, 3,  0]]
```

requirement: (if two arrays with a same first element found.. just need to sum the other elements of both arrays based on the index and maintaining order of elements)

please suggest the best way to do this? (vanilla javascript or jquery)
order of elements is important

output expected as below

```
[["Database_Config",  19, 26, 0, 0, 27, 0]
["apiDomainListener", 0,  0,  1, 1, 0,  0]
["Some_other_Config", 0,  4,  0, 0, 3,  0]]
```

Comment: Usage of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: sorry.. can you please post the pseudo code to achieve above functionality

Comment: What did you already try?

Comment: Use an object whose keys are the first elements.

Comment: @Barmar that would break the order

Comment: Loop over the array. If the key already exists, sum the corresponding elements into its value array. If the key doesn't exist, set the value array to the rest of the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the first item as key and search in the result set for a same group. Then update the values.

```js
var data = [["Database_Config", 19, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ["Database_Config", 0, 26, 0, 0, 0, 0], ["apiDomainListener", 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], ["apiDomainListener", 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], ["Database_Config", 0, 0, 0, 0, 27, 0], ["Some_other_Config", 0, 4, 0, 0, 3, 0]],
    grouped = data.reduce((r, [key, ...values]) => {
        var temp = r.find(([q]) => q === key);
        if (temp) values.forEach((v, i) => temp[i + 1] += v);
        else r.push([key, ...values]);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```